# Strlen gives an incorrect output after fgets

Tags: c, fgets, strlen

I read a string using fgets. It prints correctly but if i try to output the length using a strlen or a while until NULL it returns a bad value. Does fgets not end the string with NULL?

```
char word[256];
fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
while(word[i])
    i++;
printf("%d",i);
```

For the string aba it outputs 40.

Comment: Yes i was set to 0. That's not the problem.

Comment: Well `strlen` isn't the problem either, I promise you.  You should provide a compilable example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Try inputting some other string and see the output value of i? Are you sure you have int i =0;?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `fgets` also includes the new line character in the string. So function `strlen` counts this symbol.

From the C Standard

> 2 The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
>   the array pointed to by s. **No additional characters are read after a
>   new-line character (which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A null
>   character is written immediately after the last character read into
>   the array.

Answer (score 0):

The below code outputs proper value:

```
int main() 
    {
       char word[256];
       int i =0; 
       fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
       while(word[i])
          i++;
       printf("%d\n",i);
    }
```

Comment: How is that different from OP, except the `int i=0;` OP claims he did?